# Laravel Building Referral System- Cant display Users in Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I Building an Affiliate System for my Users. Registration with ID works fine and save all correct in my DB, but i cant see any Referrals that use my URL ID for Registration in my Example Blade.

Any one cant find the Error?

Controller:

```
    $referal_id = $user->id;

    $referer_id = $request['referal_id'];

    $referalUserData = [
        'referer_id' => $referer_id,
        'referal_id' => $referal_id,
     ];

    $insert = ReferralUser::insert($referalUserData);
```

Blade:

```
<tr>    
<th>#</th>   
<th>User Id#</th>
<th>User Name</th>                          
<th>Registration Time</th>
</tr>                      
</thead>    
 <tbody>                        
@if(!empty($referalUser))                        
@foreach($referalUser as $referData)                             
<tr>                           
<th scope="row">{{$referData->id}}</th>                           
<td>{{$referData->referal_id}}</td>                            
<td>@for($i=0;$i<count($referData['names']);$i++)  {{$referData['names'][$i]['name']}}                              @endfor                            
</td>                            
<td> {{$referData->created_at}}<br/>   <span class="label label-primary">                             
 {{Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($referData->created_at))->diffForHumans()}}  </span>  </td>
</tr>                       
 @endforeach                        
@else

<div class="alert alert-noreferals">
      <strong></strong><span>No referrals!</span>

    </div><br/><br/>                        
@endif
```

Ignore the `created_at` Timestamp.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you convert the $request object to an array?

```
$request['referal_id'];
```

That looks suspicious. Typically you would use

```
$request->input('referal_id')
```

or via dynamic properties

```
$request->referal_id
```

To access a given value.

Are you getting an error? Anything in the log files?

Comment: But this save it successful in my DB. Do you mean the "Data" is the Problem, because i have changed "$data" to "$request"

Comment: No errors , just cant display the users in my Blade, in DB all is correct. Get the Message from Blade: "No referrals!"  i think the Problem is "$referalUserData".

Comment: Oh I follow you. So $request is an array but you use object notation in your view. Change `$referData->referal_id` to `$referData['referal_id']`. Do that everywhere `->` is used on referdata

Comment: Show how you pass `$referalUser` to the view.

Comment: what you mean exactly?

Comment: From your controller to the blade file. Something like `return view('referal_view', ['referalUser' => $data]);` I would guess.

Comment: In my Controller comes an next page for Registration wheres nothing to do with Referal system. Do you mean i have forget something?

Comment: It seems something is missing. What comes after `$insert = ReferralUser::insert($referalUserData);` in your controller?

Comment: `  session()->flash('user_id',$user->id);

     return redirect()->route('emailregister');

    } `

Comment: Oh i think i must do it in ProfileController.     public function ShowAffiliate(){
      return view('profile.affiliate');
    }

Comment: Ok so you've got two issues. First, `$referalUser` is never set, so there is nothing for the blade file to use. Second, you're redirecting to another page, which means you're losing your flashed session data. Its only available between single request lifecycles, redirection is making two requests. Read this for how to properly pass data to views: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#creating-views

Comment: Oh shit i have forget to setup it all in ProfileController :/ xD Thanks for your Help Friend!

Comment: Happy to help. Ta.